# How to change checkbox attribute? C++/VS

Tags: c++, winapi, controls

In Visual Studio 2010 I need to enable or disable checkbox. I have found in the manual information for the attribute but I did not find any code how to do it. Can you show me example?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368354%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You have linked to an MSI control. This is part of the Windows Installer GUI programming. If this is what you are looking for, please update the question tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable or disable controls, use the [EnableWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function.

If you want to change the checked state, you can use the [CheckDlgButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Example:

```
void MyCheckDlgButton(HWND parent, int buttonId, bool check)
{
    CheckDlgButton(parent, buttonId, check ? BST_CHECKED : BST_UNCHECKED);
}
```